# TCP Dynamic Client

Tags: spring-integration

I need to send request to two tcp external servers, Do i need to use router or need to have a separate AbstractClientConnectionFactory, tcpOutBound?

Updated code - Gary, As Suggested, I am using two connection factories, I will be communicating with two TCP servers, Is this the right way?
Cant I just use one single AbstractClientConnectionFactory for two channels?

```
 @Bean(name = "visaConnectionFactory")
public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactoryVisa() {
    ISOConnectionProperties visa = applicationProperties.getIsoServers().getVisa();
    TcpNioClientConnectionFactory tcpNioClientConnectionFactory =
            new TcpNioClientConnectionFactory(visa.getHost(), visa.getPort());
    tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setUsingDirectBuffers(true);
    tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setApplicationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher);
    return new CachingClientConnectionFactory(tcpNioClientConnectionFactory, visa.getPoolSize());
}

@Bean(name = "mastercardConnectionFactory")
public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactoryMastercard() {
    ISOConnectionProperties mastercard = applicationProperties.getIsoServers().getMastercard();
    TcpNioClientConnectionFactory tcpNioClientConnectionFactory =
            new TcpNioClientConnectionFactory(mastercard.getHost(), mastercard.getPort());
    tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setUsingDirectBuffers(true);
    tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setApplicationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher);
    return new CachingClientConnectionFactory(tcpNioClientConnectionFactory, mastercard.getPoolSize());
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel outboundChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}


@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "router.channel")
public HeaderValueRouter consumeRouterMessage() {
    HeaderValueRouter router = new HeaderValueRouter("cardType");
    router.setChannelMapping("V", "outboundChannelVisa");
    router.setChannelMapping("M", "outboundChannelMastercard");
    return router;

}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outboundChannelVisa")
public MessageHandler outboundGatewayVisa(
        @Qualifier("visaConnectionFactory") AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory) {
    TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
    tcpOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(clientConnectionFactory);
    tcpOutboundGateway.setRequestTimeout(5_000);
    return tcpOutboundGateway;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outboundChannelMastercard")
public MessageHandler outboundGatewayMc(
        @Qualifier("mastercardConnectionFactory") AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory) {
    TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
    tcpOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(clientConnectionFactory);
    tcpOutboundGateway.setRequestTimeout(5_000);
    tcpOutboundGateway.setUnsolicitedMessageChannelName("unsolicited");
    return tcpOutboundGateway;
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "unsolicited")
public void handleUnsolicited(String in) {
    log.debug("Unsolicited response:{}", in);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate factory and adapter; also see this sample

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/main/advanced/dynamic-tcp-client

> Demonstrates a technique to dynamically add TCP clients on-demand, with caching and LRU removal.